# Sending data with js fetch and using it in php page I get error

Tags: javascript, php, post, fetch

I'm sending data to test.php page with fetch on my page and it can't pass the if check shown below on the test.php page, so the error "Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Only POST requests are allowed" comes up. What could I be doing wrong?

```
fetch("test.php", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              
              value: valueToSend
            })
          })
          .then(
            function(response) {
              if (response.ok) {
                console.log("ok")
                window.location.href = "/test.php";
              } else {
                console.log("There was an error sending the message.", response);
              }
            }
          )
```

my test.php page

```
if (strtoupper($_POST['REQUEST_METHOD']) != "POST") {
        throw new Exception('Only POST requests are allowed');
    }

    // Make sure Content-Type is application/json 
    $content_type = isset($_POST['CONTENT_TYPE']) ? $_POST['CONTENT_TYPE'] : '';
    if (stripos($content_type, 'application/json') === false) {
        throw new Exception('Content-Type must be application/json');
    }

    // Read the input stream
    $body = file_get_contents("php://input");

    // Decode the JSON object
    $object = json_decode($body, true);
    var_dump($object);
```

Comment: Beats me, but turn on the Web Console (ctrl-shift-K on some browsers) and watch the network traffic to see what you're actually sending

Comment: I don't understand what you mean beat me @BarryCarter

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit on American slang, ignore it. "Beats me" means "I don't know why either"

Comment: Why even use AJAX if you redirect and only console.log an error? Just redirect to test.php from the server

Comment: how so? I send the data and use it on that page and I also want to redirect to see it @mplungjan

Comment: I get ok response from console.log but I get error on test.php page @mplungjan

Answer (score 1):

It's simply that you are reading the bad global var.

It's not `$_POST['REQUEST_METHOD']` but it's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` which should be tested in your `if` statement.

Same problem for the content type. Use `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` instead.

`$_POST` is the array of posted values.

#### Proof of concept

As you asked if it works or not: yes, it does work.

Just paste this PHP code in a file and view it.
It contains a button which will trigger the Ajax request to itself. It displays the response directly in an alert window.

I simply took the posted JSON object and added an attribute with the current time to show that the echoed object has been altered by the PHP.

```php
<?php

if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != "POST") {
    //throw new Exception('Only POST requests are allowed');

    // For the POC, instead of throwing the exception we'll
    // display a page with a button which will trigger the
    // Ajax request to this same PHP file.
    print <<<END_OF_HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="post-to-server">POST JSON data to $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] and echo the output</button>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('post-to-server').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            fetch('$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  value: {
                    firstname: 'James',
                    lastname: 'Bond',
                    permitToKill: true
                  }
                })
              })
              .then((response) => {
                  if (response.ok) {
                    console.log('ok');
                    // Decode the JSON (it's a promise also).
                    response.json().then((data) => {
                        console.log('JSON data', data);
                        alert('Server response:\\n' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log('Could not decode the JSON response!', error);
                    });
                  } else {
                    console.log('There was an error sending the message.', response);
                  }
                }
              )
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
END_OF_HTML;
    exit; // Stop here as we just display the HTML page.
}

// We recieved a POST request.
// Let's make sure Content-Type is application/json 
$content_type = isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] : '';
if (stripos($content_type, 'application/json') === false) {
    throw new Exception('Content-Type must be application/json');
}

// Read the input stream.
$body = file_get_contents("php://input");

// Decode the JSON object.
$object = json_decode($body, null);

// Alter the echoed data by adding an attribute to the object.
$object->response_time = date('c');

// Send the JSON response.
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($object, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: i changed it but i get the same error @PatrickJanser

Comment: I used `phpinfo();` in test.php and then executed the JS fetch() in Chrome's console by adding it to a click eventListener and I got the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` correctly set to `POST` as expected. Did you try outputing some debug data from test.php and see what you get in the *Response* tab of the *Network* debugger? Oh, yes, I removed your `window.location.href = "/test.php";` to see things correctly.

Comment: @kennedyas I added a POC to show you that it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
<form action="test1.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="value" value="valueToSend" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and test1.php

```
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != "POST") {
    throw new Exception('Only POST requests are allowed');
}

// Read the value
$body = $_POST["value"];

if ($body === "valueToSend") header("location: test2.php");
else header("location: error.html");
```

Comment: As I understand in the question, he wants to send some structured JS data which is stored in a JS variable called `valueToSend` in JSON format to the PHP handler and not just a POST parameter containing the string "valueToSend". You can see that the PHP handler checks if it is recieving some JSON or not. The idea is that the communication is done with some Ajax requests and not with a full page load. But don't ask me what he was trying to do with the `window.location.href = "/test.php"` to reload the page if the Ajax request was ok...

Comment: Possibly. It would be a waste of time if the value to send was `{ "key" : "value" }` but if more, then sure